# Problems when trying to Convert polygon to raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, rasterization

Well, I'm having a problem when trying to convert polygon to raster on ArcGis 10.0.
Here is the thing: Ther output raster is much smaller than the input polygon, and the coordinate system is diferent as well! I've already tryied the environment tool from the "polygon to raster" boz, on arctoolbox, but still no success!
I observed that when I try to save on the defalt folder, my process goes ok1! But whe I select a specyfic folder my problem appear!
What could possibly be happening? Any help is welcome!

Comment: Usually this is not a problem unless the "Processing Extent" setting is set to something more specific than "Intersection of Inputs" or is set to somthing inappropriate for the analysis. Try setting the "Processing Extent" Environment Variable to the input polygon layer. It sounds like you may have already looked at the Environment Variables. What does the results panel tell you? success?

Comment: Thaks for your answer, but I've already tryied settind the processing extent to the input polygon layer, but no success...

Answer (score 1):

I would fix the coordinate system issue first.

Try a few thing like: at the environmental setting go to output coordinates, it should be the same as input option.

The other thing go to the data frame properties. At the coordinate system it should be  the same coordinate system you have for the polygon. If not change it to that one.

Try to [project](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007q000000) the raster to the original coordinate system. Check if the results is what you want.